# Can I process a DataFrame using Polars without constructing the entire output in memory?

Tags: python-polars

To load a large dataset into Polars efficiently one can use the lazy API and the `scan_*` functions. This works well when we are performing an aggregation (so we have a big input dataset but a small result). However, if I want to process a big dataset in it's entirety (for example, change a value in each row of a column), it seems that there is no way around using `collect` and loading the whole (result) dataset into memory.

Is it instead possible to write a LazyFrame to disk directly, and have the processing operate on chunks of the dataset sequentially, in order to limit memory usage?

Answer (score 7):

### Edit (2023-01-08)

Polars' has growing support for streaming/out of core processing.

To run a query streaming collect your `LazyFrame` with `collect(streaming=True`).

If the result does not fit into memory, try to sink it to disk with `sink_parquet`.

### Old answer (not true anymore).

Polars' algorithms are not streaming, so they need all data in memory for the operations like join, groupby, aggregations etc. So writing to disk directly would still have those intermediate `DataFrame`s in memory.

There are of course things you can do. Depending on the type of query you do, it may lend itself to embarrassingly parallellizaton. A sum could for instance easily be computed in chunks.

You could also process columns in smaller chunks. This allows you to still compute harder aggregations/ computations.

### Use lazy

If you have many filters in your query and polars is able to do them at the scan, your memory pressure is reduced to the selectivity ratio.

Comment: I'm getting this error `PanicException: sink_parquet not yet supported in standard engine. Use 'collect().write_parquet()'`. What would be the difference between `lazy_frame.collect(streaming=True).write_parquet()` and `lazy_frame.sink_parquet()`?

Comment: @Guz Same here , It seems `sink_parquet` only supports some limited number of predicates/filter/joins before using it. It is working fine if you directly send the output of `scan_parquet` with a `.select()` columns option to `sink_parquet`

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered a case where Polars manages memory much better using Lazy. When using the `join` function I highly recommend using scan_csv/scan_parquet/scan_ipc if memory is an issue.

```
import polars as pl

# combine datasets
PATH_1 = "/.../big_dataset.feather"
PATH_2 = "/.../other_big_dataset.feather"

big_dataset_1 = pl.scan_ipc(PATH_1)
big_dataset_2 = pl.scan_ipc(PATH_2)

big_dataset_expanded = big_dataset_1.join(
    big_dataset_2, right_on="id_1", left_on="id_2", how="left"
)
big_dataset_expanded = big_dataset_expanded.collect()
```

Comment: `scan_ipc` or `scan_parquet` it self returns a `LazyFrame` . In the end when you collecting it to convert it into a DataFrame , it throws an error if the file size is out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide some examples since Ritchie already explained it. This shows how to write a LazyFrame to disk (streaming to file) without loading it all into memory:

```py
(pl.LazyFrame({'a':'word', 'b':'word2'})
 .sink_parquet('test.parquet')
)
```

This is how to do the same for operations that aren't currently supported by streaming - like `.concat_list()`

```py
(pl.LazyFrame({'a':'word', 'b':'word2'})
 .with_columns(joined = pl.concat_list(pl.col('a'), 
                                       pl.col('b'))
              )
 .collect(streaming=True)
 .write_parquet('test.parquet')
)
```

```
pl.scan_parquet('test.parquet').fetch()

shape: (1, 3)
┌──────┬───────┬───────────────────┐
│ a    ┆ b     ┆ joined            │
│ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---               │
│ str  ┆ str   ┆ list[str]         │
╞══════╪═══════╪═══════════════════╡
│ word ┆ word2 ┆ ["word", "word2"] │
└──────┴───────┴───────────────────┘
```